# Forward UITouch event from superview to a UIControl subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing a radial menu, where when you long press (UILongPressGestureRecognizer) on the screen, it pops out a menu of buttons, and I can drag my finger (which is already touching the screen) over one of the buttons, which selects, then when I let go, it performs an action specific to that button.

I currently have the radial menu as a UIControl subclass, and I'm trying to override `beginTrackingWithTouch:` and `continueTrackingWithTouch:`, but the long press that shows the menu (adds it to the superview), does not get transferred to a touch recognized by the UIControl.

Any ideas how I can "forward" this touch event from the UIControl's superview to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but you should really watch the WWDC session about scrollviews of this year. And then watch it again. It contains a fantastic amount of information, and most certainly an answer to your question. It is session 235:  advanced scrollviews and touch handling techniques.

Comment: Yeah I did watch that actually. But I believe my question is a little different. I tried implementing hit testing logic, but all that is irrelevant if I can't "transfer" a touch point from the previous long press onto the UIControl subclass (the radial menu) in the first place. I think that's my main obstacle here.

Comment: Can you maube reverse the logic and have the radial view be the view that receives the long pres. And then when it recognizes, you make it appear? Or have one superview that does both the long press and drag? Maybe then it becomes similar to the last part of the wwdc section ( with the delay touches recognizer). Just thinking out liud here :) .

Answer (score 1):

I would do this...

The long press handler:

```
-(IBAction)onLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
  CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //create the radial view and add it to the view

    CGSize radialViewSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80);
    radialView = [[RadialView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x - radialViewSize.width/2, point.y - radialViewSize.height/2, radialViewSize.width, radialViewSize.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:radialView];

    radialView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [radialView onTouchUp:[radialView convertPoint:point fromView:self.view]];
    [radialView removeFromSuperview];
    radialView = nil;
  }
}
```

In your radial view: (I suppose that the radial view keeps the buttons in an array)

```
-(void)onTouchUp:(CGPoint)point
{
  for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
    if ([button pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:button] withEvent:nil]) {
      //This button got clicked
      //send button clicked event
      [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's not perfect, since the touch events don't get forwarded to the radial view (as you asked), but it let's you click the buttons. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is great! I never thought of switching on the UILongPressGestureRecognizer's state. I guess this is the best that can be done, since only the class that started the long press can handle it's end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same behavior you're looking for, but I recently had to overcome the exact same issue when developing my [Concentric Radial Menu](http://www.snarkybits.com/crm/). The thing I discovered very quickly was that views added to the view hierarchy during the touch event do not get re-hit-tested and therefore seem unresponsive until the next event comes around.

The solution I used, which I can't say I love, was to implement a custom UIWindow subclass that intercepts `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and forwards those events to the "active" radial menu.

That is, the menu registers with the window upon activation, then unregisters when being unloaded. If done atomically, this is actually a pretty safe technique, I just wish it were cleaner than it is.

Best of luck!